# Post New Contact: Xero changes name field when contains 2 spaces

Tags: xero-api, xero

When posting a new contact to the Api Endpoint for Contacts (repeated in the API Explorer), Xero changes the name field when it contains two consecutive spaces.

This appears to be unexpected behaviour.  Is this a bug?

Steps to repeat in API Explorer:

POST Payload:
`{ "Contacts": [ { "Name": "Bagels -  Hawthorn" } ] }`

RESPONSE Payload:
`{ ... "Contacts": [ { "Name": "Bagels - Hawthorn", } ] }`

(Note the two spaces are now only one space.)

Comment: Don't you think this question would be better served via a support ticket to Xero? I'm curious though, there's no way the API would return invalid JSON as shown in your question so what are you actually looking at to verify the problem? If it's in the web UI you should be aware that HTML visually collapses spaces in most text nodes

Comment: @Phil, thx.  I'll create a support ticket with Xero.  The scenario I'm working with actually uses the Xero.NetStandard.OAuth2 SDK to create a new contact, but I've noticed that when I use it to create a contact with a name that has two spaces in it, it collapses to one space.  This is problematic.
I know it's not the SDK, it's Xero's API because I repeated it in the API Explorer.  I'm wondering if others have come across this and if I'm missing something (Obviously, I'm not an expert). Thx again.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. **Where** exactly are you seeing the value with the space removed?

Comment: If I try to create a contact with the name 'Bagels -  Hawthorn' (2 spaces between '-' and 'Hawthorn') it actually creates and returns a contact with the name 'Bagels - Hawthorn' (1 space between '-' and 'Hawthorn'

Comment: **WHERE** are you seeing that result? Is it literally in an API response as viewed through logging or a debugger or are you looking at it using some sort of web UI?

Comment: In my Visual Studio debugger

Comment: Ok, that definitely sounds like a legitimate bug. I'm honestly surprised there'd be any editing / normalising of the name provided.

Comment: Xero have now stated that it is like this by design.